# JPQL JOIN doesn't return results

Tags: sql, ejb, jpql

My JPQL JOIN query doesn't return any results.

I'm trying to join TargetBean and TipBean on the TargetBean primary key:

```
public class TargetBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


@Entity
public class TipBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private TargetBean target;
```

My query looks like this:

```
    List<Object[]> tipList = 
            (List<Object[]>)em.createQuery("SELECT tb.result, tg.actualResult "
                    + "FROM TipBean tb JOIN tb.target tg") 
            .getResultList();
```

Do you notice something wrong with this query or what goes wrong?

Comment: Try removing the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation, I don't think it is appropriate in this context (it is used with inheritence).

Comment: Glad I could help. I added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation, I don't think it is appropriate in this context (it is used with inheritence).